# Spark AR text integration issue

Tags: facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to add current day of the week and time to my Spark AR filter for Instagram. But when I try to publish the filter, I am getting **The effect contains text that's not integrated into the scene of the effect"** this error.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you should ensure the text is in the scene at all times
You can do this by tracking so that the text doesn't move too much or move outside the scene e.g face tracking

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong. But when I converted my saved file into .mp4, it worked. And was able to successfully upload the file to SparkAR.